# Not getting updated DataContext on window close button click

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a basic WPF application based on MVVM, in that i have to implement save prompt if the user has any unsaved changes on the screen and he tries to close it without saving.

For the same i have handled the closing event of the window and i am presenting a prompt.

My problem is i see the DataContext is stale, it's not having the latest changes in UI.

**One more observation is that i see the correct DataContext on closed event of the window.**

Any clues..?

Answer (score 0):

Binding would not have stopped when your Window is Closing and will continue to work. Have you checked output for binding errors?

Show me the code :)